# Windows can't recognize a Pendrive compatible with ubuntu

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to connect the USB (10GB of 64) to the computer and open it using Windows 10, but nothing happens.

When I open in in Ubuntu, I can see the files.

How can I solve this without loosing any information?
How can I avoid this to happen in the future?

Comment: What file system is it formatted to?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the files to your Ubuntu system and then format your pen drive to exFAT file system. Then again copy your files to pen drive and check in with ur Windows.

Comment: He should use exFAT filesystem.